# how to compare two percentages to prove for statistical significance

Tags: spss, excel, contingency-tables

I have problem to compare the two percentages and to get the statistical significance for these two different percentage. I just want to approve whether these two percentages are significant or not significant using Microsoft Excel or SPSS. I attach with the image of my data. 
[image: to compare two percentages]

Hopefully your help may lead me to correct method. Thank you.

Comment: These appear to be row-wise percentages. Do you know the underlying numbers for each cell &/or row? Be aware that if you are asking for code, that would be off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the underlying numbers (as @gung asks), this is a classic case for a $\chi^2$ test. This is a basic test of association, and will give you a p-value to assess statistical significance. Just beware that $\chi^2$ tests are sensitive to sample size, so if you have a large sample, even small, non-substantive differences may come up as significant. I like to pair my $\chi^2$ tests with an effect size, which gets more at whether the difference is important. To calculate the effect size for a cross tab, use Cohen's *w*, which is easily created by calculating the standardized $\chi^2$ statistic - this is just calculating $\chi^2$ where the cell values are the overall table proportions (where the cell value is $N_{cell}/N_{table}$) (reference:  Cohen, J. (1992). Statistical Power Analysis. *Current Directions in Psychological Science*, 1(3), 98–101).

SPSS does it easily in its crosstab function. I think you have to hand calculate the $\chi^2$ statistic in Excel and then use one of its distribution formulas to get the p-value.

This [link](http://www.indiana.edu/~educy520/sec5982/week_12/chi_sq_summary011020.pdf) gives you more details on it, or you could refer to any introductory statistics text. This [link](http://case.truman.edu/Documents/SPSS%20Crosstab%20Categorical%20Data%20Analysis%20II-Chi-Square%20Test.pdf) and this [link](http://www.csun.edu/~egodard/364/hdos/SPSS-Crosstabs.pdf) give you how to do it in SPSS.